# Recovering the SDE of Vasicek model.

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we have the solution to the ordinary Vasicek model:

$$r_t = r_0 e^{-a t} + b(1 - e^{-a t}) + \sigma \int^{t}_0 e^{-a (t-s) } dW_s$$

How do I use the Ito's lemma to recover the SDE

$$dr_t = a(b - r_t)dt + \sigma dW_t$$

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply with $e^{at}$ and take the derivative, then apply simple product rules with one deterministic factor and further algebraic manipulations:
$$
d(e^{at}r_t)=b\,d(e^{at}-1)+σ\,e^{at}\,dW_t\\
e^{at}(dr_t+ar_t\,dt)=ab\,e^{at}\,dt+σ\,e^{at}\,dW_t\\
dr_t=a(b-r_t)\,dt+σ\,dW_t
$$